# dplyr convert data to wide format with two keys

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID, Type, Unit, Value, Status
A, L1, cm, 100, F
A, L2, %, 70, F
A, L3, cm, 100, F
A, L4, %, 80, F
B, L1, cm, 100, T
B, L2, %, 70, T
B, L3, cm, 100, T
B, L4, %, 80, T
```

And I want to convert this to wide format:

```
ID, L1(cm), L2(%), L3(cm), L4(%), Status
A, 100, 70, 100, 80, F
B, 100, 70, 100, 80, T
```

I'm using the spread function in dplyr, with the key being Type and value to be Value. And I think I will have to do it again on the ID column. I would like to know if there's a standard way to do this or if there's a more concise way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  Create a concatenated column with 'Type' and 'Unit' either with `paste` or `unite` (less flexible), and then `spread` to 'wide' format after removing the unwanted columns

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  mutate(TypeUnit = paste0(Type, "(", Unit, ")")) %>%
  select(-Type, -Unit) %>%
  spread(TypeUnit, Value) 
#   ID Status  L1(cm)  L2(%)  L3(cm)  L4(%)
#1  A      F     100     70     100     80
#2  B      T     100     70     100     80
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
Type = c(" L1", " L2", " L3", " L4", " L1", " L2", " L3", 
" L4"), Unit = c("cm", "%", "cm", "%", "cm", "%", "cm", "%"
), Value = c(100L, 70L, 100L, 80L, 100L, 70L, 100L, 80L), 
Status = c(" F", " F", " F", " F", " T", " T", " T", " T"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

@akrun 's answer is definitely beautiful. 
If you also want to try `reshape`, below should also work but you might need to rename the column names afterwards.

Using the same data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
             Type = c(" L1", " L2", " L3", " L4", " L1", " L2", " L3", " L4"), 
             Unit = c("cm", "%", "cm", "%", "cm", "%", "cm", "%"), 
             Value = c(100, 70, 100, 80, 100, 70, 100, 80), 
             Status = c(" F", " F", " F", " F", " T", " T", " T", " T"))
```

Using package `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID + Status  ~ Type + Unit, value.var = "Value" )
```

Output

```
  ID Status  L1_cm  L2_%  L3_cm  L4_%
1  A      F    100    70    100    80
2  B      T    100    70    100    80
```